# Magento 1.9.x : Newsletter Subscription Event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, newsletter

Is **there an event in Magento 1.9.x for Newsletter Subscription from the Profile page?**

How do I find out when a user updates their newsletter subscription preference from this page?

I tried `controller_action_predispatch_newsletter_manage_save` and `newsletter_subscriber_save_after` events. Although not getting any subcriber data through either of the following:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
 $isSubscribed = $event->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed');
```

or

```
$subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
$data = $subscriber->getData();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try listening to the `model_save_after` event with something like this (pseudocode):

```
public function checkSubscriptionPreference(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $model = $observer->getObject();
    if (!$model instanceof Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber) {
        return;
    }

    if ($model->isSubscribed()) {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

There are other similar events that you could use depending on what you need, such as `model_save_before`, `model_load_before`, etc.

Comment: Source: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/ - see Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:390 for the code that fires the event.

Comment: Are there other activities as well that throw the same event? I am looking for something specific to Newsletter subscription.

Comment: Never mind.. got your point. let me try this out.

Comment: I couldn't find any other events that are more specific and would allow you to do this - but it's very possible I may be missing something so I recommend you double-check. Good luck!

Comment: I went ahead with this implementation itself. Working well for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's a better observer to use, 'newsletter_subscriber_save_after', which is specific for that model, that way it doesn't fire on every observer save

Comment: For some reason in 1.9 there is no events related to newsletter or subscriber